# NSIS – Error MySql with Redirection using nsEXEC::ExecToStack --- Why is ExecToLog vs ExecToStack different errors

Tags: mysql, redirect, cmd, import, nsis

I have search forums over too many days the test results can be repeated. 
[**QUESTION**]
What causes the MySQL failure and/or the CMD parsing error of directory name?
[**NSIS Script follows**]

```
importdbs:
DetailPrint "IMPORT SQL files to db=$dbname User=$login Pswd=$password"
StrCpy $1 "$folder\bin\mysql.exe"
StrCpy $2 "$srcepath$srcescript"

DetailPrint "MySqlDir: $1 input: $2"
ClearErrors

nsExec::ExecToStack /OEM '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /C "$1" -u$root -p -v -D $dbname < "$2" > "c:\_temp-c\ckprnout.txt"' 

Pop $3  # Get Results

StrCmp "error" $3 +1 +2
DetailPrint "IMPORT return-error: $3"
DetailPrint "IMPORT return-OK: $3"
```

[**RESULTS (test01) from nsis log panel**]:

IMPORT SQL files to db=demo User=root Pswd=
…. Password entered ….
MySqlDir: c:\PROGRA~1\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe
         input: c:_temp-c\dumps\dump-20170604-demo.sql

**IMPORT return-OK: 1 <=error**

[**NOTE:**]
changing nsExec::**ExecToStack** .... to nscExec::**ExecToLog** ....
Yields different Error

[**RESULTS (test02) from nsis log panel**]:

IMPORT SQL files to db=demo User=root Pswd=
…. Password entered ….
MySqlDir: c:\PROGRA~1\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe
         input: c:_temp-c\dumps\dump-20170604-demo.sql

**'c:\PROGRA~1\MySQL\MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Comment: You realize that it is impossible for me to debug this? What is `$folder`? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that does not involve MySQL. The "is not recognized as an internal or external command..." error comes from cmd.exe.

Comment: You said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190117/nsis-compile-mysql-not-recognised-as-operable-program-why-does-nsexecexect#comment75635518_44190117) in a comment a couple of days ago that you were going somewhere else and now you are back asking almost the same question! You clearly have not learned anything about asking good questions and this question will get the same treatment as the previous (almost duplicate) question: zero answers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. Hope it works for you.

```
importdbs:
DetailPrint "IMPORT SQL files to db=$dbname User=$login Pswd=$password"
StrCpy $1 "$folder\bin\mysql.exe"
StrCpy $2 "$srcepath$srcescript"

System::Call 'kernel32::GetLongPathName(t r1, t .r3, i ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}) i .r4'
StrCmp $4 error +2
StrCpy $1 $3

DetailPrint "MySqlDir: $1 input: $2"
ClearErrors

ReadEnvStr $R0 COMSPEC
ExecDos::Exec /TOSTACK `"$R0" /c "$1" -u$root -p -v -D $dbname < "$2" > "c:\_temp-c\ckprnout.txt"`

Pop $5  # Get Results

StrCmp "error" $5 +1 +2
DetailPrint "IMPORT return-error: $5"
DetailPrint "IMPORT return-OK: $5"
```